# Laplacian and inequality of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $D=\{(x,y) | x^2+y^2 < 1 \}$ . Let $f$ and $g$ be a $C^2(D)$ be such that g is bounded and $f$ approaches infinity as $x^2+y^2$ approaches $1$ and moreover $\Delta f=e^f$ and $\Delta g \geq e^g$ at all points of $ D$. Here $\Delta$ is the Laplacian. Prove $f \geq g$ on D.

My strategy is to prove by contradiction. Suppose at point say $(x_0,y_0)$, $g>f$.
Now we define a new function h=g-f.At this point $\Delta h >0$. Now I want to conclude that h is less than average of of all the values and arrive at the contradiction. How to proceed after this?

This class just the knowledge of real analysis. So I cannot use tools from PDE.

Comment: Do you mean that $g$ is bounded rather than $D$?

Comment: Thanks . I just corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, we define $h:=g-f$. Now, take $\left(x_0,y_0\right)\in D$ such that
$$h\left(x_0,y_0\right)=\max_D h.$$
This is possible since $h(x,y)\to -\infty$ as $x^2+y^2\to 1$ and hence the set
$$\left\{(x,y)\in D:h(x,y)\geq h(0,0)\right\}$$
is compact.

Now, we have
$$e^{g\left(x_0,y_0\right)}-e^{f\left(x_0,y_0\right)}\leq\Delta g\left(x_0,y_0\right)-\Delta f\left(x_0,y_0\right)=\Delta h\left(x_0,y_0\right)\leq 0$$
and hence
$$g\left(x_0,y_0\right)\leq f\left(x_0,y_0\right)$$
or, equivalently, $h\left(x_0,y_0\right)\leq 0$. But since $h$ attains its maximum in $\left(x_0,y_0\right)$ we get
$$h\leq 0\quad\text{in }D$$
which proves the claim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Why is the laplacian of h negative?

Comment: @Thomas Look at the functions $h_1(x):=h(x,y_0)$ and $h_2(y):=h(x_0,y)$. Then, $h_1$ attains its maximum at $x_0$ (hence $h_1^{''}(x_0)\leq 0$) while $h_2$ attains its maximum at $y_0$ (hence $h_2^{''}(y_0)\leq 0$). Now, we can write $\Delta h(x_0,y_0)=h_1^{''}(x_0)+h_2^{''}(y_0)\leq 0$.

Comment: Just another remark about my answer: There is nothing special about $e^f$ and $e^g$ here. In fact, the proof still works if we assume $\Delta f=\phi(f)$ and $\Delta g\geq\phi(g)$ for some arbitrary increasing function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Maybe I should not read MSE after a long day of programming and before going to sleep :D... indeed that follows almost immediately from your choice of the point as the maximum...